# Drupal 7 failed to open stream: Permission denied in image_gd_save()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying to generate and scaled image for thumbnails, scaling image has no problem and when use

```
image_save($_image) // Works Fine
```

(using the same folder an replacing) this code has not problem, the problem starts when I tried to save images in another destination folder using destination parameter:

```
image_save($_image, $destination) //throws errors
```

then the error occurs:

> Warning: imagejpeg(C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-devel\sites\default\files): failed to open stream: Permission denied in image_gd_save() (line 284 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-devel\modules\system\image.gd.inc).

I'm working into a Windows xampp and using the function `is_write` of PHP, return true, no problem with permissions.

I had been trying for a time and I don't know what's happening, no problem with permissions.

This is my code:

```
$destination = 'public://gallery/thumbs/';
$filepath = drupal_get_path('module', 'gallery_blueprint') . '/img/large/1.jpg'

// Someplace before function
file_prepare_directory($destination, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
_generate_thumb($filepath,$destionation,300,NULL);

// Function code
function _generate_thumb($filepath, $destination_path, $width = NULL, $height = NULL) {
  $_img = image_load($filepath);
  $scaled = image_scale($_img, $width, $height); // Return true

  $result = image_save($_img, $destination_path); //Error occurs whit destination path

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is an stupid answer but will be written.

the function `image_save()` when you pass throw the $destination folder, it doesn't write the name by default, finally you need to write a final absolute name path, the name of file is required or throws.

```
Warning: imagejpeg(C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-devel\sites\default\files): failed to open stream: Permission denied in image_gd_save() (line 284 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-devel\modules\system\image.gd.inc).

//finally you need to write whole filepath
image_save($_img, $finalname_path) //$filname_path = public://gallery/thumbs/1.jpg
```